# Lando - Difficulty setting "extension=mongodb.so" value in php.ini file for MongoDB Service setup on Drupal

Tags: php, mongodb, lando

I'm having trouble configuring the `extension=mongodb.so` value in the server's php.ini file while setting up the MongoDB service on Drupal. The installation process for everything else is going smoothly.

Here is the content of my .lando.yml file:

```
name: drupal
recipe: drupal10
config:
  webroot: web
  composer_version: 2.2.16
  via: nginx
  php: 8.1
  database: 'mariadb:10.4'
services:
  myservice:
    type: phpmyadmin
  mongoservice:
    type: mongo
    portforward: true
    creds:
      - mongo
  phpservice:
    type: php
    build_as_root:
      - pecl install mongodb
      - docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
    config:
      php: config/php.ini
```

And here is the code in the php.ini file:

```
[PHP]

extension=mongodb.so
```

I'm receiving the following warnings:

```
Build process completed successfully Installing '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mongodb.so' install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongodb-1.15.3 configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location You should add "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini
```

Could you please provide any advice or guidance on this issue? Thank you in advance.